# Rendering javascript one at a time

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript that draws hundreds of lines on a webpage.  When the page loads, it renders all the lines at the same time.

To make the question simpler lets say I have a js file that has 3 functions.

```
drawing_one
drawing_two
drawing_three
```

Currently when the page loads, one, two and three are drawn on the page simultaneously.  What is the best way to have it where when it loads, nothing is drawn yet.  After some interval, say 1 second, it will draw everything one at a time.  In this example, it'll draw one, then two, then three after the interval time given.  After everything is drawn, it'll clear everything and then start over again.

Comment: What are the functions that do the drawing? We need to know if they are async or sync.

Comment: use callback functions

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post, you can try setTimeout functions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    setTimeout(function () {
        drawing_one();
    }, 1000);


});
```

Then drawing_one() could look like this:

```
function drawing_one() {

    //do stuff, then

    setTimeout(function () {
        drawing_two();
    }, 1000);

}
```

Repeat this pattern for drawing_two() and then for drawing_three()

```
function drawing_three() {

    //do stuff, then

    clearDrawings(); // you define this

    setTimeout(function () {
        drawing_one(); // start over
    }, 1000);

}
```